# What happened to local pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

My questions are marked in code comments in the snippet below.

```
int *foo(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    return &b;
}
int *foo2(){
    int aa = 44;
    int bb = 40;
    return &bb;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *p = foo();
    int *p2 = foo2();

    int  a = 700;
    int *b = & a;

//  cout<<*b<<endl; /* what & why the difference from adding & removing this line?? */
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<*p<<endl; /* what & why happened to "p" */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this I don't even? Bad programming practice is what this is.

Comment: This is quite possibly the worst question I've seen on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tomalak yeah,*_*,sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `foo()` and `foo2()` you are returning pointers to local variables.  These locals have automatic storage and it is *undefined behavior* to use a pointer to them once they go out of scope.  Therefor `p` and `p2` contain nothing useful.  It might work, it might not.

I can't understand your question very well, so I hope I got it all.

Comment: +1 for bravery. (And for "automatic storage")

Comment: @Nelson thanks for your patience. I just wanna know more detail about the "undefined behavior".

Comment: @Zhao: **Undefined behaviour** results when programs attempt to do things for which the standard defines no semantics, and requires no diagnostic either. Examples include dereferencing invalid pointers and dividing by zero. Executing such programs may cause them to produce incorrect results, crash, silently "work", or even format the hard drive. **Avoid like the plague.**

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means that C++ doesn't define what the result of your code is.  It might crash.  It might print the great question of life, the universe, and everything.  If it does work, it will work only by chance.

Comment: @Tomalak thank you,I got it.If I remove the line:cout<<a<<endl; The pointer "p" will always return the value of "bb", yes?

Comment: @Zhao Rocky: No, the pointer `p` will not return the value of `bb` because `bb` doesn't exist anymore. It went away when the function `foo2()` returned. So `p` will not be valid. *Anything* can happen if you attempt to dereference an invalid pointer.

Comment: @Zhao: No. `bb` no longer exists, and `a` has _nothing to do with it_. Read the answers you have been given, and also find yourself [a decent C++ book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Comment: @In silico So the console outputs "40" just by chance,and is not right,yes?(I just mean the result,not the code)

Comment: @Zhao Rocky: Yes, the reason why you still get `40` is because nothing has overwritten the memory location for the variable `40`. But you should never write code that depends on that kind of knowledge. This `cout<<*p<<endl;` invokes undefined behavior, where *anything* can happen (including working just fine).

Comment: @Zhao Yes, completely by chance.  The code is not right.

Comment: @In Silico: :) Thanks! I just confused about why the console always printed "40",now I see,"always" sometimes means "by chance".:)

Comment: @Zhao Rocky: I'm glad we were able to clear things up, but please pick up [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) where these kinds of things are covered and much more because your question demonstrates that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how C++ works.

Comment: Yeah,And thank you all for your patience and good answers and I have to apologize for my Bad Question.

Answer (score 1):

Before I attempt to answer the questions in the comments of your code snippet, let's step through this:

```
int *foo(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    return &b;
}
int *foo2(){
    int aa = 44;
    int bb = 40;
    return &bb;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *p = foo();
    int *p2 = foo2();
```

In both `foo()` and `foo2()`, you're returning a pointer to something located in the function call stack (that is, `a`, `b`, `aa`, and `bb`), which will go away when the function returns. Within the function a pointer to variables `a` or `b` in `foo()` or a pointer to variables `aa` or `bb` in `foo2()` will point to something valid.

But when the function returns, those variables will cease to exist. So in both of these functions the returned pointer will not be valid, and consequently `p` and `p2` will be invalid as well.

```
    int  a = 700;
    int *b = &a;
```

You're assigning the address of the variable `a` to pointer `b`.

```
//  cout<<*b<<endl; /* what & why the difference from adding & removing this line?? */
```

Adding the line will dereference `b` and print out the value of the pointee (in this case, the value of variable `a` which is 700).

```
    cout<<*p<<endl; /* what & why happened to "p" */
```

Since `p` is invalid as explained earlier, it will invoke undefined behavior, meaning *anything* can happen. That can include it working just fine (which I doubt), printing garbage values, crash outright, or explode your computer. Just don't try to dereference an invalid pointer.

Comment: +1 for diligence. -1 for "points to garbage" and "it will print garbage". There are _no_ defined semantics here; it may not print garbage, but instead cause a tear in the fabric of space and time.

Comment: i think it might segfault also (?)

Comment: @phoxis: That's a possible outcome, yes.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Sorry, my mistake. I wasn't thinking hard enough. :-P

Comment: @Insilico: You can have the point for diligence now. :) Good answer.